# Google Sheet hide formula in frozen title bar

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Is there a way to target a formula to the cell(s) below it?  I have a complex formula that transposes and builds results across multiple columns and rows.  I like to play with sorting and filtering in the data, so the formula ends up getting moved around because it is in the first cell of the data.

As an example, Row 1 is frozen and has the titles for each column.  I have the formula in A2 and the data is populated all the way down A and into B, C, and D.  If I do sorting or filtering on column A, the formula moves.  I would like to move the formula up into the title bar (A1) so it stays in the same place and never moves.  But I want it to still populate the data starting in A2.  Then I also want the title cell (A1) to still show the text of the column title and not the formula....so basically hiding the formula in the cell's background.  Is this possible to do?

EDIT:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MbvMGhrVNhXGfMi4Q5VjwODLgDpKtXtMj0PtKre3Q2U/edit?usp=sharing

Added an example to get a better visual to make my question clearer.  Basically what I have right now is a formula in cell A2 "Data1" that populates A2:C.  It will populate and transpose vertically and horizontally as much as necessary to show the data.  That fills out the cells automatically.  I want to move the formula itself up into A1 ("Title 1") but still have the cell read "Title 1".  When I do that, I lose Data1, Data2, Data3 because it moves the entire result of the formula up 1 row.  I want to force the results to be pushed down 1 row so the results stay the same but the formula is tied to the frozen bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, you ask for this:

```
={"header for A", "header for B"; ARRAYFORMULA(A2:B)}
```

note that to avoid array error you need to define a header for each column even if empty `""`

[image: 0]

---

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRIM(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEN($A$3:$L), {
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('T1'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "T1", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('B1'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "B1", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('T2'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "T2", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('B2'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "B2", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('M1'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "M1", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('B3'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "B3", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('M2'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "M2", ),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99))=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$3:$L),,999^99)),
    TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('B4'!$A$3:$L),,999^99)),1,0)), "B4", )}, ),
 " ", "♦")),,999^99))), " "), "♦", " ")))}
```

[image: 0]

**note:** if you get `ARRAY LITERAL error` you will need to add more `""` 
like: `={"", "", "", ""; ARRAYF....`

Comment: I think my question was too vague, so I copied in exactly what I have for a formula.  This is something I believe you might have written for me awhile back and it works really well.  Basically the formula in the pink cell fills in data in the pink cell + all of the yellow cells.  It works really well.  I want to move the formula to the purple cell, so the formula never moves, but I want the results of the formula to still start at the pink cell and fill in all of the yellow.

Comment: Basically when I move the pink cell formula to the purple, the results start showing in the purple cell.  I want the purple cell to say "Title 1" but have the formula in there as well, but the results to stay in the pink + yellow cells.

Comment: Just wondering if my question is more clear now that I updated the spreadsheet with a better example...